# Angularjs image not showed : unsafe:background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to show an image in my Angularjs application here is the code :

```
<img  src="background-image: url({{image.url}})" />
```

Where `image.url` is a scope variable with the value `http://localhost/assets/photo/41/photo.jpg` hosted on an apache server on localhost.

The GET request fail with the error :

```
unsafe:background-image: url(http://localhost/assets/photo/41/photo.jpg):1
GET unsafe:background-image: url(http://localhost/assets/photo/41/photo.jpg) 
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try this:
<img  ng-src="image.url" />

Comment: @nikolaMM94 not only `ng-src="image.url" ` it would be in `{{}}` interpolation

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't really pay attention, yeah you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `img` tag incorrectly

```
<img  ng-src="{{image.url}" />
```

& your image url coming from server would be `/assets/photo/41/photo.jpg` instead of `http://localhost/assets/photo/41/photo.jpg`, Actual domain is not required when you are working on same domain.

Just not clarified what you want to do..It also seems like you may want to use `background-image` in that case `ng-style` would be helpful

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+ image.url+')' }"></div>
```

**Update**

As URL is of other domain & you wanted to show it in do that url as `trustedResourceURL` using `$sce` service

```
$scope.getTrustedResourceUrl = function(url){
   return $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(url)
};
```

**HTML**

And get other domain URL to get working it without prepending `unsafe:` before url then you need to sanitize `imgSrc` in config & whitelist url regx in it.

```
app.config(function($compileProvider) {
    var imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*(https?|ftp|file):|data:image\//;
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist);
});
```

Comment: not working, it's not the same domain i run two server a server angularjs and http server that would be used for assets and static resources.

Comment: not even i think the `image.url` is not interpolated in `{'background-image': 'url('+ image.url+')' }' with my code i got the error in my question